# How to provide a common style for DataGridView in VB.net

Tags: css, vb.net, datagridview, formatting

How to create a class or some other stuff to make all the DataGridView inside my project of same format i:e AlternativeRowColor, ForColor,BackColor and Other properties. Currently i have to go to each of the control property to set , it sucks when user requested to change and property of Grid as i have to change in all the DataGridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Class FrmArticle

       Private Sub GridFormatting(ByVal DGV As DataGridView)
    DGV.ForeColor = Color.Black
    DGV.BackgroundColor = Color.AliceBlue
    DGV.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Brown
    DGV.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DodgerBlue
    DGV.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.CadetBlue
    DGV.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGoldenrod
    DGV.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
         End Sub

        Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                GridFormatting(DataGridView1)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

or

```
Module GridFormat
    Public Sub GridFormatting(ByVal DGV As DataGridView)
    DGV.ForeColor = Color.Black
    DGV.BackgroundColor = Color.AliceBlue
    DGV.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Brown
    DGV.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DodgerBlue
    DGV.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.CadetBlue
    DGV.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGoldenrod
    DGV.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
    End Sub
End Module


Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
               GridFormatting(DataGridView1)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd add that you could add this as a helper function in another class (as a shared method, or alternatively in a module). You could even make it an extension method if you wanted ;)

Comment: Where to add this GridFormatting function?

Comment: we may add in helper class or directly

Comment: Am new bee to VB.net , Can u explain where to add helper class and how to inherit the same to Forms?

Comment: Add with your class or set separate module and call it

Comment: My form already inherits with System.Windows.Forms.Form as shown below , How do i inherit this new Class?
Public Class FrmArticle
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Comment: This works , Thanks, but if i want to include it in seperate class and  call it so as to avoid writing the same function in each form.

Comment: How to add the below properties??
DGV.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = ??
        DGV.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle=??